# Disabling touchpad after suspend/resume

Tags: touchpad, suspend, hibernate, synaptics

There are several questions about disabling touchpads on laptops on this site, but none of them seem to quite answer my question.

I want to disable my touchpad (I've done that bit) and keep it disabled after a suspend/resume (I am failing here).

I am running Ubuntu 12.04 on a cheap Chinese laptop.

I have an executable file /home/yannick/bin/notouch which looks like this:

```
xinput set-prop `xinput list | grep "ImPS/2 Generic" | awk '{print $7}' | sed "s/id=//"` "Device Enabled" 0
```

The script runs xinput once to get the id number of (what turns out to be) my touchpad, and then runs xinput again to disable the touchpad. I have it in my .bashrc and in other places.

At present, when I suspend and then resume my laptop, the touchpad comes alive again and I really want to stop this happening. So I also have a file

/etc/pm/sleep.d/97disable_touchpad (owned by root, +x) which looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
case "$1" in
    thaw|resume)
        /home/yannick/bin/notouch 2>/tmp/notoucherrors
        ;;
    *)
        ;;
esac
exit $?
```

And darn it, it doesn't work! Indeed the script does seem to run after a resume, and the content of /tmp/notoucherrors is:

```
Unable to connect to X server
Unable to connect to X server
```

Dammit I want my touchpad to stay disabled when I hibernate and resume. How do I make this happen?

Here are two other things I tried and that I couldn't get to work:

1) $synclient TouchpadOff=1

This returns

```
Couldn't find synaptics properties. No synaptics driver loaded?
```

2) System Settings -> Mouse and Touchpad. I only have options for mouse there (I would even go so far as to say that ubuntu thinks that my touchpad is a mouse for some reason). In particular there is no option to turn the touchpad off -- all I have is mouse options (general, pointer speed, drag and drop, double-click timeout).

Answer (score 1):

I have a partial workaround which will do for now -- I randomly set the DISPLAY variable and hope. Works for now. I also run notouch as my userid (rather than root).

My disable_touchpad script in sleep.d now looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
case "$1" in
    thaw|resume)
        echo "running notouch" >> /tmp/notouchlogger
        export DISPLAY=:0
        su -c - yannick /home/yannick/bin/notouch 2>>/tmp/notoucherrors
        ;;
    *)
        ;;
esac
exit $?
```

and it seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

With root privileges, try creating the file /etc/pm/sleep.d/0000trackpad.

```
sudo -i gedit /etc/pm/sleep.d/0000trackpad
```

enter you password if required past following code in gedit and save file

```
#!/bin/sh
case "$1" in
    resume)
        DISPLAY=:0.0 su USER -c '/usr/bin/synclient TouchpadOff=0' ;;
esac
```

log out and back in again

Answer (score 0):

Create a file `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/95-disable-touchpad.conf` with following content:

```
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "libinput touchpad disable-by-default"
        MatchIsTouchpad "on"
        MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
        Driver "libinput"
        Option "SendEventsMode" "disabled"
EndSection
```

This disables all touchpad devices from sending X events.

- If you later want to enable (first) touchpad:

```
  xinput --set-prop "$(xinput --list --name-only | grep -i touchpad | head -n 1)" "libinput Send Events Mode Enabled" 0 0`
```

- to disable it again manually:

```
xinput --set-prop "$(xinput --list --name-only | grep -i touchpad | head -n 1)" "libinput Send Events Mode Enabled" 1 1
```

Tested successfully on  Dell Latitude 5520 with Debian Bullseye on suspend/hibernate/resume/thaw, but it should be similar elsewhere.

Also, one can apparently use `Option "SendEventsMode" "disabled-on-external-mouse"` instead so the touchpad is only disabled if no external mouse is connected, and is left enabled otherwise (but I have not tried that configuration).